# Random Records from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow, and I apologize for it being more or less a repeat or if I've posted anything incorrectly. I'm trying to follow the code in [Random record from MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb), but still struggling to retrieve 4 random records from my MongoDB in Node.

In the Mongo shell, I can successfully retrieve 4 random records with this:

```
db.reccs.find( { genre: { $in: ['fantasy']} } ).limit(4).skip(Math.random() *   db.reccs.count( { genre: { $in: req.query.test} } ))
```

However, in my Node.js server.js file, this code returns no errors and the first 4 records it finds, not a random 4:

```
  app.get('/comics', function(req, res) {
  var comics = db.collection('reccs').find( { genre: { $in: req.query.test} } ).limit(4).skip(Math.random() * db.collection('reccs').count( { genre: { $in: req.query.test} } )).toArray(function(error, comics) {
  if (error) {console.dir(error+"error!")}

  res.send(comics)
}) })
```

I'm totally stumped, so I'd appreciate any thoughts on why this works in the Mongo shell but not in server.js. Thank you!

edit - I believe this question is different because it is not about the Mongo shell, but Node.js - the solution in the linked question does absolutely work in the shell, just not in Node.js.

edit 2 - If anyone ever comes across this, this [MongoDB count() undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148875/mongodb-count-undefined) along with the comment below should help!

Comment: MongoDB access in node.js is async, so you need to provide a callback to `count` to get the result. Only then can you make the subsequent `find` query.

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyHK , got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() * some number will not give you integer ...

```
console.log(Math.random() * 22)
// 12.282829137984663
```

Therefore your skip (probably) never executes. Try

```
var numRecordsToSkip = Math.round(Math.random() * numRecords, 0)
.limit(4).skip(numRecordsToSkip) ...
```

Comment: Note: `var numRecordsToSkip = ~~(Math.random() * numRecords);` converts to integer quicker

Comment: @MiKeBu very interesting approach - never knew you could do it this way.